# How to do command "grep -oP" in a line that contains special Characters?

Tags: bash, unix, edi

How can I grep a line that contains special characters.

as for example I have a file containing this text

```
ISA^G00^G          ^G00^G          ^G12^G14147844480    ^GZZ^G001165208      ^G160601^G1903^GU^G00401^G600038486^G0^GP^G>~GS^GTX^G14147844480^G001165208^G20160601^G1903^G600038486^GX^G004010VICS~ST^G864^G384860001~BMG^G00^G^G04~MIT^G000000591^GKohl's AS2 Certificate Change June 21, 2016~N1^GFR^GKOHL'S DEPARTMENT STORES~PER^GIC^GEDIMIO@kohls.com^GTE^G262-703-7334~MSG^GAttention Kohl's AS2 trading partners, Kohl's will be changing.
```

I would like to grep the line under MSG segment

using this command:

**grep -oP 'MSG.\K[\w\s\d]*' < filename**

Expected Result :

**Attention Kohl's AS2 trading partners, Kohl's will be changing.**

Actual Result:

**Attention Kohl**

How will I do it?

Comment: `grep -oP 'MSG.\K.*' filename`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern:

```
grep -Po 'MSG.\K[\w\s\d]*'
```

is matching just `Attention Kohl` because you have a single quote after that which will not be matched by any of the `\w`, `\s`, `\d` tokens.

You also have `,` and `.` within your desired portion, so you need to match those too. Also, `\d` is actually a subset of `\w` so no need for explicit `\d`.

So you can do:

```
grep -Po 'MSG.\K[\w\s,.'\'']*'
```

Or if you you just want to match till the end:

```
grep -Po 'MSG.\K.*'
```

Comment: This works tnx mate ;) I just added some additional for some cases

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want grep everything after MSG? That would be simpler with other methods.
Also I see there are multiple `^G` characters in your file, adjacent to MSG word as well. Not sure if you want to exclude those while grep'ing.

Back to your given regex - you can add `\W` which will match a non-word character and give you desired result.

`grep -oP 'MSG.\K[\w\s\d\W]*' filename`

Also no need to use `<` operator to `grep` here.

Comment: I want only to grep the message excluding ^G and any others only the message and also what other methods do you mean could you kindly give some tnx ;)